# python pandas select rows that match one condition and write to a new csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to select rows that match a condition and write to a new csv file. Here's my code and some sample data and i'm sure the type of 'id' is string. It only gives me the header row in the new file.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df[(df['id'] == '48')].to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```

I'm wondering where the problem is. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Add sample data of `df` dataframe

Answer (score 1):

It might be happening because id would be a numerical value.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df[(df['id'] == 48)].to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```